# Knockout with changing pre-populated multiselect in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have a field that is a multi-select dropdown that is populated from a model that will be updated on occasion by the end user.  I am trying to retrieve the selected value for knockoutjs so when I submit it to the database it sends the array of user-selected options.

All the examples I've been able to find has been using enums or an already populated javascript object with fixed options, not changing values like my case.

Below is the table that is populated from the model.  I've included the other fields that I have working for context, but the one in questions has `@HTLM.DropDownList`:

```
<td><input  class='required number form-control' maxlength="9" stringlength="9" data-bind='value: id, uniqueName: true'/></td>
                    <td><input class='required form-control' data-bind='value: firstName' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required form-control' data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ID", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.UserGroups, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "chosen-groups"})
                    </td>
                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeUser'>Delete</a></td>
```

I've built the knockout portion off of knockout's editable grid example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html)

I'm assuming it has something do with the `data-bind: options` like in the example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is going to populate the options for you server-side based on `ViewBag.UserGroups`, so there is no need for an `options` binding.  You just need to bind `selectedOptions` to your view model property.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.UserGroups,
    new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "chosen-groups",
          data_bind = "selectedOptions: yourProp" })
```

Comment: Great.  Is there a way to get the values from the list vs just it's supposed index.  Right now it shows 1, 2, and/or 3 instead of the text value.

Comment: What is "the list" and "it"?

Comment: The values listed (aka, the list) that can be selected are "Group1", "Group2", "Group3".  However, they appear as ["1", "2", "3"] in the array.